# How to rotate your player with mouse (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

my player can move and can look around with mouse but my player dont rotate with the mouse it only goes the way it was designed to. i want my player to go where my mouse is pointing but like in valorant (this is a first person game). i want it in c# unity.

Comment: Unity has a premade FPS character controller that will help you. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-first-person-character-controller-urp-196525

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transform.Forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) for this, assuming you are already rotating the player based on where they are looking. Transform.Forward is a vector of the local Z-axis of a gameobject. Which means it always points forward. You can add it to the position or if you're doing a physics based approach; add it to the rigidbody's velocity. by either setting it directly or using [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)